# Why does the majorana equation preserve handedness?

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, chirality, majorana-fermions, charge-conjugation

In the "QFT Nutshell" by A. Zee, it is stated that

> The Majorana equation is 
>   $$i\not\partial\psi=m\psi_c$$
>   where $\psi_c$ is the charge conjugated spinor $\psi_c = \left(C\gamma^0\right)\psi^*$. As $\psi_c$ is right handed if $\psi$ is left handed, the Majorana equation, unlike the Dirac equation, preserves handedness.

I have completely no idea what the author means when he says "the equation preserves handedness".

Comment: Do you appreciate handedness (chirality) and how the massive Dirac's equation violates it? (connects left- to right-handers).

Comment: I think understand the chirality. It is how the spin of the particle relates to its direction of motion. I am not really sure how the massive Dirac's equation violates the chirality. But if I were to guess, I would say that by looking at the Dirac's Lagrangian, the mass terms connect the left handed spinor to the right handed spinor. Is that the correct way to see?

Comment: You are close, but you are confusing helicity with [chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)#Chiral_symmetry), which makes all the difference: for Tony, "handedness" is chirality! Go to a world without right-chiral particles. Note that you cannot write a massive Dirac equation there, but you can a Majorana equation.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thank you very much!